# Autolayout problems when sizing AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have an `AVPlayerLayer` in a `UIViewController`. When the device is in portrait mode I want the video to fill the width of the screen and stay in the 16:9 ratio. When the device is in landscape mode, I want the video to fill the height of the device, and still stay in the 16:9 ratio. It should use the superview, rather than the safe area guides. This is the same as how videos are displayed in the Photos app on iOS. I'm having trouble setting this up with autolayout though. How can I do this?

On my video view I have these constraints:

```
16:9 ratio for width:height
Trailing space to superview >= 0
Leading space to superview >= 0
Align Center Y to superview
Bottom to superview >= 0
Top to superview >= 0
```

At the moment these don't work because it says it needs a constraint for Y position or height.

Comment: Let's see what you've tried. Post some code and we can offer some pointers.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I'm using autolayout on storyboard, rather than code

Comment: Fairly certain you cannot create an `AVPlayerLayer` from a storyboard. Have you done this yet?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I have done it. You can if you use a `UIView` and subclass it. Anyway, I've posted above what I've got in the storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio is governed by the video itself, so you do not need to account for it in your view. Just pin the top, leading, trailing, bottom constraints to your superview, remove your aspect ratio constraint, and set the following property on AVPlayerLayer:

```
playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
```